# Facing issue in flutter Assertion failure in -[FlutterStandardReader readValueOfType:], FlutterStandardCodec when exit from better player full screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing below issue in Flutter.

*** Assertion failure in -[FlutterStandardReader readValueOfType:], FlutterStandardCodec.mm:478
2024-01-05 11:12:47.719231+0530 Test[23449:1332323] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Corrupted standard message'
*** First throw call stack:

Thanks